# Spring NullPointerException this.service is null

Tags: java, spring, service, controller, nullpointerexception

I have problem with NullPointerException, every POST on /register endpoint, the NullPointerException shows that service is null
Controller with /register

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Validated
public class SecurityController {

    private final UserService service;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    private ResponseEntity<UserDTO> registerUser (@RequestBody @Valid RegisterDTO registerDTO) {
        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create("/user")).body(service.createUser(registerDTO));
    }
```

UserService

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService implements UserServiceApi {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    public UserDTO createUser(RegisterDTO user) {
        if (user.equals(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This nickname is already taken");
        }
        if (user.equals(userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()))) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This email is already taken");
        }
        // Encoding password
        user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        // On creating new Account it's going to have USER role
        Role role = roleRepository.findByName("USER");

        String username = user.getUsername();
        String password = user.getPassword();
        String email = user.getEmail();

        User dto = buildUser(username, password, email, role);

        userRepository.save(dto);
        return UserDTO.builder()
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .email(email)
                .build();
    }
```

Other controller that use service, I dont know maybe that's the cuase of problem

```
@RestController(value = "/user")
@AllArgsConstructor
@Validated
public class UserController {
    private final UserService service;

    @GetMapping("/getusers")
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getAllUser() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(service.getUsers());
    }
```

Comment: have you tried Autowiring that service?

Comment: Can you show us how you injected the Service?

Comment: Remove `@Validated`from your controllers and make your method `public`. `@Validated` on the class level serves a different purpose and isn't needed here. Leads to creation of a proxy, due to yuor method being `private` this leads to a method invocation on the proxy instead of passing it through to the actual object. The proxy doesn't have anything set, hence a `NullPointerException`. Rule of thumb your controller methods should be `public` anyway.

Comment: @M.Deinum making public method works, good to know about `@Validated`, thank you

Comment: @TeddyTsai I injected service with Lombok by `@AllArgsConstructor` as I understand it

Comment: @Stultuske I tried to Autowire it but it didnt work